# How to make entry at a specific place(position) in Registry Tree using Java Preferences

Tags: java, preferences

I am using java Preferences API to make entry in Registry of Windows. I am able to enter value in Registry. By default all keys are entered at HKCU\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs location. What if I want to Make Entry at a Specified location like HKLM\SOFTWARE\ABC\XYZ

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting them in a different location?

Comment: @user3757014 I want to distinguish my product from that of java
Like HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\MY_COMPANY\\MY_PRODUCT_1\\..

Comment: If your package is something like com.mycompany.myapp then the key created by Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(class) will be HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Prefs\com\mycompany\myapp so will be entirely independent.